# static layer on local costmap

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d, static-map, move-base, layered-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to use a static layer (in /map i.e. global frame) in the local costmap. So when the robot moves, I want the lethal obstacles in this static layer that are also in the local costmap, to be inflated. How do I do this?

I know static layers are usually added in the global costmap, but for a special case I want the local planner to access this information.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200573/static-layer-on-local-costmap/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2015-01-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are currently issues with the static_layer and rolling costmaps. A (unmerged) pull request that may fix this can be found here: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/pull/246.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2015-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2015-01-09**:
Doesnt seem to work, or maybe its trying to solve something else. For now, I havegot this to work in two ways:

1. Create a custom layer and mark all intersection points between a static layer and master layer
2. Publish the static map as a sensor(pointcloud) in /map frame for use by ObstacleLayer